# Быстрые запросы в PMA

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

коллеги.

Хотелось бы узнать, существует ли способ сохранить запросы для быстрого исполнения в phpMyAdmin, и если да, то как?

Требуется вызывать запрос выборки с 3 связанными таблицами переименованием и столбцов для последующей выгрузки в csv, потому просто писать его каждый раз не лучший вариант.

Заранее благодарю за ответы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте представление (create view).